# How to read waypoints in xively

Tags: location, xively

There is a nice explanation how to store locations on Xively
https://xively.com/dev/docs/api/metadata/waypoints/
https://xively.com/dev/docs/api/quick_reference/api_resource_attributes/

but there is no example how to read stored waypoints ?
GET https://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/FEED_ID_HERE only gives me last location, but I need historical waypoints.